# How should an initial state computation (ex: validation) be passed back to a parent in React?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say we have a setup with a parent component and a Child component. I want to follow the "dumb" component pattern where data flows from top to bottom and then alerts the parent using the `onChange` callback.

I am a little confused though, how to apply this to a component that might have a Form inside. Let's say the Parent needs to know if the data within the component is valid but the validation logic is within the Form component. Is there a good way to still follow this pattern without calling the form component through a `ref`?

In a typical MVC the validation/computation would be done on a model which would be passed around.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
   constructor () {
      this.state = {
        value: {},
        isValid: this.isValid()
      };
   }
   render () {
      return (
        <Form props={this.props.fields} onChange={this.onChange}></Form>
      );
   }
  
   isValid () {
      //what should I do here? 
   }
  
   onChange (change) {
     this.setState({
        values: change.values,
        isValid: change.isValid
      });
   }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
   render () {
      //return some form stuff 
   }
  
   onChange (value) {
      //fancy internal validation logic
 
     this.props.onChange({
        values: value,
        isValid: resultFromValidationLogic
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: on the parent onChange you aren't setting your state. you should look into flux pattern as that is probably the best way to handle this. but you should still be able to handle this how you are attempting to. I didn't really follow the issue though, what is wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: @JohnRuddell re following flux pattern, what if I wanted the form component to be standalone (theoretically should not rely on environment).

The problem with what I am trying to do now is that there doesn't seem to be a great way to compute a property (is data valid?) without referencing the child component if the validation logic lives in the child.

I guess the question is more about where should complex "computed" properties such as results of validation logic live in a React application

Comment: you should have the is valid logic in the form. the parent can display that valid data or a valid status that comes from the child. but your form should handle the validation.

Comment: @JohnRuddell ideally, yes. But say I need to know from the parent whether a child is valid (for computing, based on multiple states if a "next" button should be shown)

Comment: then store an array on the parent state that pushes more valid child states to it... that child valid state should come from the child though. child does validation. parent gets the valid child and does something with it

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes, that works great if we know that a Child starts invalid, but this doesn't work if a Child may start as valid (i.e. a change on Child may not necessarily need to happen for the child to be valid)

Answer (score 0):

If `Parent` needs to know the result of the validation, then I would put the validation in `Parent`.

In React's top-down paradigm, it doesn't make sense to have something stored/performed in a lower order component that a higher order component needs to know about. The exception being input values; they are the only thing that should be in your change handler.

Additionally, this way `isValid` doesn't need to be in the state. It can be derived from the state. I would make a call to the validation in the Parent render function.

Here's my modest rewrite:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      values: {}
    };
  }

  isValid(values) {
    // perform validation here
  }

  handleChange(values) {
    this.setState({
      values: values
    });
  }

  render() {

    const isValid = this.isValid(this.state.values);

    return (
      <Form
        props={this.props.fields}
        values={this.state.values}
        onChange={(values) => this.handleChange(values)}
        isValid={isValid}
      />
    );

  }

}

class Form extends React.Component {

  handleChange(values) {
    this.props.onChange(values);
  }

  render() {
     // return some form stuff
  }

}
```